# Error during debugging of Salesforce pipeline

Tags: salesforce, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

When I try to launch the debugger for debugging pipeline, I get this, error in eclipse.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your digital connection and the cartridges which are referenced to it. (right click > Properties > Project References). Most probably there is a cartridge which is marked but you don't have it anymore or it's closed.